# Linux grep what in file 1 is in file 2

Tags: awk, sed, grep, regular-expression, diff

**File 1:**

```
1234567890123456,00,00,000
1111111111111111,11,11,1111
```

**File 2**

```
1111111111111111,11,11,1111
9999999999999999,99,99,999
```

So i want to know what in file 1 is in file 2 which is

> Output:

```
1111111111111111,11,11,1111
```

Comment: How have you tried to solve this problem so far, and what have the results been?

Comment: @John I don't know how to resolve it so that's why am asking if someone know

Comment: We're willing to help. We're not willing to do everything for you. You need to make an effort to figure this out on your own first. I would start by reading @Sundeep's link.

Comment: @John, i already make effort before asking the question. but failed, that's why i asked my question and by the link which Sundeep provided i were able to resolve my issue ! so thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following command i were able to resolve my issue

`grep -Fxf file1 file2`